# Update json array from another json array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge

**EDIT: Updated json configs to include additional key, val pairs at the same level as "appArr"**

I would like to update the matching keys from one json array with a subset from a different json array.

I have a global json config like this:

```
var config_global = {
  "sub-heading": "This is the sub-heading",
  "content": {
    "par1": "asdf",
    "par2": "qwerty",
    "par3": "12345"
  },
  "appArr": {
    "app1": {
      "id": "ID_001",
      "name": "Application 1",
      "url": "https://app1.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true
    },
    "app2": {
      "id": "ID_002",
      "name": "Application 2",
      "url": "https://app2.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true
    },
    "app3": {
      "id": "ID_003",
      "name": "Application 3",
      "url": "https://app3.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have another json array that will keep all the sub-keys and only update the items in my second json array:

```
var config_local = {
  "content": {
    "par1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure aperiam inventore nemo, asperiores dolorem nisi voluptate omnis quam sit doloremque expedita architecto dicta, at consequatur."
  },
  "appArr": {
    "app1": {
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": true
    },
    "app2": {
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": false
    },
    "app3": {
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": false
    }
  }
}
```

The final config must have the complete `config_global` with the updates from `config_local`.

I tried using `Oject.assign()`, but this replaces the app configs instead of updating it.

The final config should look like this:

```
var config = {
  "sub-heading": "This is the sub-heading",
  "content": {
    "par1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure aperiam inventore nemo, asperiores dolorem nisi voluptate omnis quam sit doloremque expedita architecto dicta, at consequatur."
    "par2": "qwerty",
    "par3": "12345"
  },
  "appArr": {
    "app1": {
      "id": "ID_001",
      "name": "Application 1",
      "url": "https://app1.html",
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": true
    },
    "app2": {
      "id": "ID_002",
      "name": "Application 2",
      "url": "https://app2.html",
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": false
    },
    "app3": {
      "id": "ID_003",
      "name": "Application 3",
      "url": "https://app3.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it.

JS objects can't have same key names like you have in your question. I am assuming that's a typo, so I fixed it the way it should be.

```js
var config_global = {
  "appArr": {
    "app1": {
      "id": "ID_001",
      "name": "Application 1",
      "url": "https://app1.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true,
    },
    "app2": {
      "id": "ID_002",
      "name": "Application 2",
      "url": "https://app2.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true,
    },
    "app3": {
      "id": "ID_003",
      "name": "Application 3",
      "url": "https://app3.html",
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": true,
    }
  }
}

var config_local = {
  "appArr": {
    "app1": {
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": true,
    },
    "app2": {
      "is_visible": false,
      "in_list": false,
    },
    "app3": {
      "is_visible": true,
      "in_list": false,
    }
  }
}

var result = Object.keys(config_global['appArr']).reduce((mem, key) => {
  mem[key] = { ...config_global['appArr'][key],
    ...config_local['appArr'][key]
  }
  
  return mem;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @arup. This worked as I wanted it. If I have another key, val pair at the same level as the appArr key (eg. "title": "My Application One"), would I need to change anything in the code?